# How to properly install PySide via pyenv?

Tags: python, pyside

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 with Python 3.3.4, installed via pyenv.

Running `sudo apt-get install python3-pyside` installs PySide in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PySide`, and I can make a symlink to that in my pyenv Python's site-packages directory. This means I can `import PySide` in Python, but I get `ImportError` when trying to import `QtGui` from `PySide`; ditto for similar modules as well:

```
ImportError: cannot import name QtGui
```

The PySide directory includes the `QtGui.cpython-33m-i386-linux-gnu.so` file, but it's not being accessed, I guess. I have fiddled with `PYTHONPATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` without success. I can't find much available information on this, so any advice would be appreciated.